# Drupal 8 module page not found

Tags: php, routes, drupal-modules, drupal-8

i work on Drupal 8, and i try to make my first module but when i call http://localhost/LearningDrupal/hello_world adress i've a page not found. There is a capture of the architecture + routing file :

[architecture and routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5ywC.png)
I have activated the module in Drupal by checking the HelloWorld box on the Local section and i've clic on install, the module was installed correctly. Why i can't reach my module then ?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot "\" before Drupal when you define your controller.
It must be: 
_controller: '\Drupal\hello_world.....'
Modify it and clear all the cache.
I wish this can help you